# Video texture on THREE.Geometry

Tags: three.js

The only examples i can find are of video textures being used on PlaneGeometry's or BoxGeometry's. I have a custom plane that i have a video applied to. The video plays (colors change) and shows however the scale is off (looks like its zoomed in).

Video playing on top right, green plane is a custom Geometry which the video is on.

[image: THREE.JS]

**THREE.Geometry**

```
this.geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

this.geometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3(900, 0, 840)
    new THREE.Vector3(-900, 0, 1200),
    new THREE.Vector3(900, 900, 840),
    new THREE.Vector3(-900, 900, 1200),
);

this.geometry.faces.push(
    new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2),
    new THREE.Face3(1, 3, 2),
);

this.geometry.computeFaceNormals();

this.object = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this._videoMaterial());
```

**videoMaterial function**

```
_videoMaterial() {

    let videoImage = document.createElement('canvas');
    videoImage.width = 480;
    videoImage.height = 204;

    this.videoImageContext = videoImage.getContext('2d');

    this.videoImageContext.fillStyle = '#211e79';
    this.videoImageContext.fillRect(0, 0, videoImage.width, videoImage.height);

    this.videoTexture = new THREE.Texture(videoImage);
    this.videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    this.videoTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    this.videoTexture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

    return new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: this.videoTexture,
        overdraw: true,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });

}
```

Comment: Did you add uv coordinates to your geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As prisoner849 said, you need to add UVs to your geometry so it knows how to map the texture on its surface

```
// Add UVs of face 1
this.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
    new THREE.Vector2(0, 0)
    new THREE.Vector2(0, 1),
    new THREE.Vector2(1, 0)
]);

// Add UVs of face 2
this.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
    new THREE.Vector2(0, 1)
    new THREE.Vector2(1, 0),
    new THREE.Vector2(1, 1)
]);

this.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate();
```

You might need to tweak the order of the UVs to match the order of your vertices on the faces, but you want an arrangement like this:

[image]

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Geometry.faceVertexUvs